# JavaScriptCore nested "call" performance issue

Tags: javascript, javascriptcore

If I define a function

```
inc = function(x) { return x + 1 }
```

and make a nested invocation of it

```
inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(inc(1)))))))))))))))))))))
```

this will result in the value `22`. If I revise the nested expression to instead make use of `call`, passing in `null` for `this`, as

```
inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, 1)))))))))))))))))))))
```

this will also produce the value `22`.

But, on JavaScriptCore this second form appears to consume *O*(2^*n*) memory, where *n* is the number of nested calls. This is not the case if I try this JavaScript in Firefox or Chrome so it seems to be isolated to JavaScriptCore.

I have very little JavaScript experience (almost none). I don't have a feel for the tradeoffs that various JavaScript implementations might make, nor whether it is reasonable for the example code to be expensive in some implementations (providing generic support for closures or some such), while efficient in others.

My question is: Is this code inherently problematic? Should it be rewritten to be structured in a different way? Or is the code fine—does JavaScriptCore simply have a bug?

I've done some experimentation where refactoring a few of the inner calls to temporaries will "truncate" the memory doubling behavior

```
var temp1 = inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, 1)))))));

var temp2 = inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, temp1)))))));

inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, inc.call(null, temp2)))))));
```

Comment: I'd sure call that a bug.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy. I've filed a rdar with Apple.

Comment: Moved rdar to WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139847

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is in reality nothing more than a bug report, with two of the three questions this post asks being primarily opinion-based.

Comment: The question is not subjective. It is about whether the behavior of a particular JavaScript VM is normal. Also, other programmers will want to know about the problem since iOS is a common dev target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on comments on this question, the consensus is that there is no fundamental problem with the code as written, but that instead this is a bug in JavaScriptCore.

For the [ticket filed](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139847), it has been confirmed as reproducible and has been imported into Apple's Radar system.

Comment: Just wondering when inc(x) normally desugar internally into inc.call(window, x) . Does null has to do something on this .

Comment: @jsHero I tried a test involving `inc.call(window, inc.call(window, inc.call(window, ...` and it exhibited the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I dont understand why this issue is closed some apple developers should probably reply with cause of this bug .Anyways its a great find @mike.